# bootstrap with angular navbar flex-column blank

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

In my angular project, I try to insert a bootstrap navigation bar to the left of my screen but I have a little blank that I cannot remove even with a `container-fluid`.

I use this code for the navigation bar :

```
<!-- admin.component.html -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/themes">Themes and categories creation</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is called in my app component like this :

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<app-topbar></app-topbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Example :
[image: Exemple]

I also tried with some css on my `container-fluid` without success.

How can I remove this little blank ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Whats your outer html and css that you are using? The one which contains the tobar and the router-outlet

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping container fluid here...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-topbar></app-topbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And keep your other html without container-fluid

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin/themes">Themes and categories creation</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
  </div>
```